# UDDI registration of wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, uddi

I am trying to create a Java Web Service where client will send some xml using SOAP . I could create a wsdl from eclipse and deploy the same on the cloud tomcat server . That WSDL on cloud server is also working as I tested from SoapUI software ReadyAPI .

Now I have to create UDDI registry for the wsdl of my webservice on cloud . Say my cloud wsdl is as below :

http://99.999.999.99:8080/CalculatorWS/services/TestXML?wsdl

Can someone please let me know the steps I have to follow to create an UDDI registry for this .

Comment: Hi Sudeshna, this isn't a site for guiding users on how to do specific things. You need to try something and come back if you encounter a *specific* problem. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi - I have been trying this in eclipse for last 2 days but it is not working , When I click on UDDI Main then nothing is happening . I posted here after considering several sites and videos .

Comment: Hi notyou - Please could you answer this . We developers help/guide each other in stackoverflow by sharing urls , steps  to give knowledge on specific things or solve a problem  . We respect each other's strength knowing that when someone is raising it here , he has tried a lot before that . This is a site for answering a professional developer's post in civilized polished language.

Comment: *We respect each other's strength knowing that when someone is raising it here , he has tried a lot before that* - unfortunately (not directed at you), this is untrue. There are several “gimme teh codez” or “please guide me how to do x” questions here every day. It is a Q&A site, and basically *Can someone please let me know the steps I have to follow...* is off-topic. Again, not personal against you, but such is the site rules.

Comment: Download Judd and ruin it